# ExtJs Triton Theme Components's Styling Issue

Tags: extjs

I'm using Extjs Triton theme and I want to reduce some field's padding,height and fontsize values. I've tried some methods but I couldn't do that. When I used to triton theme all components are appearing a little bit big.( For example TextField,Combo,... etc. )[image]

Comment: Why don't you override the related SASS variables ? e.g. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#css_var-S-$form-text-field-height

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the default tpl of an input using this prop [fieldSubTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Base.html#cfg-fieldSubTpl)

```
 Ext.create({
        xtype: 'textfield',
        value: 'test',
        fieldSubTpl: [
            '<input id="{id}" data-ref="inputEl" type="{type}" {inputAttrTpl}',
            ' size="1"', // allows inputs to fully respect CSS widths across all browsers 
            '<tpl if="name"> name="{name}"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="value"> value="{[Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(values.value)]}"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="placeholder"> placeholder="{placeholder}"</tpl>',
            '{%if (values.maxLength !== undefined){%} maxlength="{maxLength}"{%}%}',
            '<tpl if="readOnly"> readonly="readonly"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="disabled"> disabled="disabled"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="tabIdx != null"> tabindex="{tabIdx}"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="fieldStyle"> style="{fieldStyle}"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="ariaEl == \'inputEl\'">',
            '<tpl foreach="ariaElAttributes"> {$}="{.}"</tpl>',
            '</tpl>',
            '<tpl foreach="inputElAriaAttributes"> {$}="{.}"</tpl>',
            ' class="{fieldCls} {typeCls} {typeCls}-{ui} {editableCls} {inputCls}" autocomplete="off"/>', {
                disableFormats: true
            }
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Symply change classes or style inside this and you'll become the painter of your input fields

Answer (score 0):

```
This is what we changed to arrive at the smaller look:

Add these vars to your themes sass variables:

$form-field-font-size: 12px;
$form-field-font-weight: 600;
$form-field-height: 23px;
$form-field-padding: 2px 6px 2px 2px;
$form-label-font-size: 12px;
$form-label-horizontal-spacing: 4px;
$form-label-line-height: 14px;
$form-label-vertical-spacing: 4px;
$form-display-field-font-weight: 600;
```